# Semantic-ui-react: Search results not visible

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, semantic-ui-css

I've been trying to get semantic ui search results to appear, but for the life of me, all I get when searching is this:

[As you can see, the search results are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjGWk.png)

I have imported the semantic-ui-css in my index.js file:

```
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
```

I'm using a super basic data set to test:

```
const cities = [
    {
        key: 0,
        city: "New York City",
        usState: "New York"
    },
    {
        key: 1,
        city: "San Francisco",
        usState: "California"
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        city: "Chicago",
        usState: "Illinois"
    }
];
```

(this array comes after the imports but is included above to keep the code section shorter)

and am using the [standard search](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search#search-example-standard) from the docs:

```
import React from "react";
import { Search } from "semantic-ui-react";
import _ from "lodash";

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        results: [],
        value: ""
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.resetComponent();
    }

    resetComponent = () =>
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, results: [], value: "" });

    handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, value });

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.state.value.length < 1) this.resetComponent();

            const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.value), "i");
            const isMatch = result => re.test(result.city);

            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                results: _.filter(cities, isMatch)
            });
        }, 500);
    };

    handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) =>
        this.setState({ value: result.city });

    render() {
        const { isLoading, results, value } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <Search
                    type="text"
                    size="big"
                    loading={isLoading}
                    results={results}
                    value={value}
                    onSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                    onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

I've even tried using my array as the data when editing the semantic-ui-react Search example, but for some reason the results aren't visible there either. How can I make the search results visible?

Thanks in advance for any comments or answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to check correct props for SearchResult,
because default SearchResult component should use the object with one of this keys: *title, description, price, image*.

see [https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search#search-example-standard][1]

Comment: Awesome, it makes much more sense now :)

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue but the answer doesn't make as much sense to me! I still can't get the results to show.

Comment: Never mind. Add resultRenderer to <Search /> that called a function that output jsx.